# Determining corners / vertices and edges of the $n$-dimensional hypercube $Q_n=\{x\in\Bbb{R}^n:|x_i|\leq 1\} $

Tags: optimization, solution-verification

I want to find the corners or vertices and afterwards the edges of the $n$-dimensional hypercube $Q_n$, defined as:$$Q_n=\{x\in\Bbb{R}^n:|x_i|\leq 1\} $$ I am doing this just as practice and I very much started confusing myself towards the end. I would appreciate, if anyone could take a look at my approach and point out any mistakes. Thank you

$Q_n$ is a polyhedron, because we can rewrite it as follows:$$Q_n=\{x\in\Bbb{R}^n: Ax\leq b\},\qquad A= \begin{pmatrix}
    \Bbb{1}_n \\
    -\Bbb{1}_n
    \end{pmatrix}\in\Bbb{R}^{2n\times n}\qquad, b=\begin{pmatrix}
    1\\
    \dots\\
    1\\
    \end{pmatrix}\in\Bbb{R}^{2n} $$Let $I=\{1,\dots,2n\}$. A point $z\in Q_n$ is a vertex if rank$(A_{I_z·})=n$, where $I_z=\{i:A_{i}z=b_i\}$ is a subset of $I$, the row indices of $A$.
Because of the form of $A$ and $b$ here, this means that for $z$ to be a vertex, out of the $2n$ inequalities $A_{j\in I}z\leq b_{j\in I}$, for exactly $n$ of them, we must have equality: $A_jz=b_j$. This must be, because we can't have less than $n$ equalities, because then rank$(A_{I_z·})\lt n$, which would imply no corners, which is a contradiction as $Q_n$ is a polyhedron, and we can't have more than $n$ equalities, because that would imply that for some $j_0\in I: z_{j_0}=-z_{j_0}=1$, which is also a contradiction.

Claim: $\forall i\in\{1,\dots,n\}:z_i\in\{-1,1\}$.
Proof of claim: For each $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ consider a matrix $A_i'=\begin{pmatrix}
    A_i \\
    A_{i+n}
    \end{pmatrix}\in\Bbb{R}^{2\times n}$, which has two rows, the $i$-th row and the $(i+n)$-th row of our matrix A, and the vector $b'=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    1
    \end{pmatrix}\in\Bbb{R}^2$. To have $n$ equalities out of our original $2n$ inequalities, we must have that for each matrix $A'_i$ and vector $b'$, exactly one of the two inequalities $A'_iz\leq b'$ is an equality. For every $i\in\{1,\dots,n\},\ A'_iz=\begin{pmatrix}
    z_i \\
    -z_i
    \end{pmatrix}\leq \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    1
    \end{pmatrix}$, so $z=1\lor z=-1$. If neither of these two inequalities was an equality, then in one of the remaining $n-1$ matrices of the form $A'$ we would get that both inequalities are equalities (otherwise there are less than $n$ equalities out of $2n$ inequalities), which would imply that $z_i=-z_i=1$, which is of course a contradiction. Therefore we have proven the claim that for all vertices $z\in Q_n:\; \forall i\in\{1,\dots,n\}:z_i\in\{-1,1\}$

Because the $n$-dimensional hypercube is found by duplicating the $(n-1)$-dimensional hypercube and connecting the vertices with additional edges, the number of vertices is doubled every time we go up one dimension. Knowing that a square (i.e. a $2$-dimensional hypercube) has $2^2$ vertices and a cube (i.e. a $3$-dimensional hypercube) has $2^3$ vertices, we can derive that the number of vertices of the $n$-dimensional hypercube is $2^n$.

Remember, that for all vertices $z\in Q_n:\; \forall i\in\{1,\dots,n\}:z_i\in\{-1,1\}$. Because there are $2^n$ ways to get an $n$-dimensional vector if for each component there are only two choices ($-1$ and $1$), and this is equal to the number of vertices of the $n$-dimensional hypercube, it must be that the set of vertices of the $n$-dimensional hypercube is exactly the set of unique combinations of $n$-dimensional vectors of $1$s and $-1$s:$$V_{Q_n}=\{\begin{pmatrix}
    1\\
1\\
    \dots\\
    1\\
    \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
    1\\
-1\\
    \dots\\
    1\\
    \end{pmatrix}\dots \begin{pmatrix}
    -1\\
-1\\
    \dots\\
    -1\\
    \end{pmatrix} \}=\{z\in Q_n : \forall_{i\in\{1,\dots,n\}}:z_i=1\lor z_i=-1 \}$$
Now to find the edges and their dimensions:
Let $x,y\in Q_n$ be vertices as previously defined and let $I_x=\{i:A_ix=b_i\}$ and $I_y=\{i:A_iy=b_i\}$. Let $I_{x,y}=I_x\cap I_y$. If rank$(A_{I_{x,y}})=n-1$, then $L_{x,y} = \{ \lambda x + (1 − \lambda)y :\, \lambda \in [0, 1] \}$ is an edge of $Q_n$. Since $Q_n$ is a bounded polyhedron, i.e. a polytope, every edge arises this way.

Similar to above, because of the form of $A$ and $b$, any $I_{x,y}$, with $|I_{x,y}|=n-1$, will result in a matrix $A_{I_{x,y}}$ with rank$=n-1$.
This means that any line segment that connects two vertices that are different in only one component $i_0\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ will be an edge of $Q_n$. Any vertex $z\in\Bbb{R}^n$ of $Q_n$ has of course $n$ components, which means that for any vertex there are $n$ vertices that differ in exactly one component. Therefore there are $n$ edges going out from each vertex and multiplied by the number of vertices, this gives us the number $n*2^n$. However this counts each edge twice, because each edge is counted from both vertices that it connects, therefore the number of edges is half that: $n*2^{n-1}$.

Now assume that $x$ and $y$ are vertices of $Q_n$ and they differ by only one component $i_0$, then we get the following $$L_{x,y} = \{ \lambda x + (1 − \lambda)y :\, \lambda \in [0, 1] \}= \{ \begin{pmatrix}
    x_1\\
\dots\\
\lambda x_{i_0}+(1-\lambda) y_{i_0}\\
    \dots\\
    x_n\\
    \end{pmatrix} :\, \lambda \in [0, 1] \}$$Because $x_{i_0},\neq y_{i_0}\land x_{i_0},\ y_{i_0}\in\{-1,1\}:\;\lambda x_{i_0}+(1-\lambda) y_{i_0}=\begin{cases}2\lambda -1,\; x=1,\ y=-1\\ -2\lambda +1,\; x=-1,\ y=1\end{cases}$. As $\lambda\in[0,1]$ these two cases are equivalent. And so, substituting this into the $i_0$-th component of $x$, we can generalise this for all $n$ vertices that $x$ shares an edge with. Doing that, we get this expression for the sequence of edges $(L_{x,i})_{i\in\{ 1,\dots ,n=\dim(Q_n)\}}$ that $x$ is an endpoint of: $$(L_{x,i})_i=\{(1-e_i)x + e_i(2\lambda -1):\ \lambda \in [0, 1]  \}$$This we can now generalise, to give us a result for all edges of our polyhedron $Q_n$. Let $(x_k)_{k\in\{1,\dots,2^n\}}\in V_{Q_n}$ be the sequence of the $2^n$ vertices of $Q_n$. Let $(M_{x_k})_k$ be a sequence, defined as follows:$$(M_{x_k})_k=\{L_{x_k,n}: x_k\in V_{Q_n}\} $$Then $(M_{x_k})_k$ is a sequence that, for each of the $2^n$ vertices $x_{k\in\{1,\dots,2^n\}}\in V_{Q_n}$, gives the sequence of the $n$ edges that each $x_k$ is an endpoint of. This gives us an expression with which we can find each edge, and the family $\bigcap (M_{x_k})_k$ gives the set of all edges.

Each edge is a line segment and therefore has dimension $1$.